# How are the two mating types, a and α, for S. cerevisiae pronounced?

Tags: cell-biology

In reading about S. cerevisiae there are two mating types, one being the Latin letter `a` and the other being the Greek letter `α`.

How are these two types pronounced such that they can be differentiated?

In other words when I pronounce the text I don't want to say 'a' for both of them; there should be a different word or phrase for each one so that they are known to be different.

Is it simply that `a` is pronounced as a and `α` is pronounced as alpha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.

Haploid mating types in *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* are MAT**a** (pronouce a as in d*a*y) and MATα (i.e. MAT-alpha).

For convenience you could also refer to the corresponding alleles as MATa or MATalpha (see also [here](http://www.yeastgenome.org/cgi-bin/locus.fpl?dbid=S000124955))